# Runtime dependency for std::string concatenation

Tags: c++, windows, linux, string, concatenation

```
std::string sAttr("");
sAttr = sAttr+VAL_TAG_OPEN+sVal->c_str()+VAL_TAG_CLOSE;
```

else where in the code I have defined

```
const char VAL_TAG_OPEN[]   = "<value>";
```

`sVal` is a variable that is retrieved off of a array of string pointers. This works fine in most of the system, windows and linux. However at a customer site, where to my belief has a version of linux on which we had done some extensive testing, produce a result as if I have never used the `VAL_TAG_OPEN` and `VAL_TAG_CLOSE`. The results I recieve is for

```
sAttr = sAttr+sVal->c_str();
```

Whats going on ?. Does std::string concatenation varies across runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the `->c_str()`? If `sVal` is a `std::string`, try removing this call. Remember that the order of evaluation is undefined, so you may end up adding pointers instead of concatenating strings, because `VAL_TAG_OPEN`, `sVal->c_str()` and `VAL_TAG_CLOSE` are all plain C strings. I suggest you use the addition assignment operator `+=`, e.g. :

```
sAttr += VAL_TAG_OPEN;
sAttr += *sVal; /* sVal->c_str() ? */
sAttr += VAL_TAG_CLOSE;
```

(which should be faster anyway).

Comment: It would probably be (*sVal), but one of course may ask why to use a pointer here if references should suffice (the perpetual std::string const& parameter, I guess).

Comment: sVal is a pointer to std::string. 
Further, sVal is the only thing that get appended anyway.

Comment: I see, I just read the answer before the question, old bad habit of mine.

Comment: Would somebody please dare to explain how this change has solved the issue?  Yes, the order of evaluation _is_ unspecified, but left-binding/right-binding of operators _is_ defined, so you will *never* end up adding pointers instead of concatenating strings...

Answer (score 1):

No, std::string concatenation should definitely not depend upon runtime, but somehow `VAL_TAG_OPEN` and `VAL_TAG_CLOSE` seem to be empty strings.

I'd guess you've some kind of buffer overflow or invalid pointer arithmetic somewhere, so that your program overwrites the memory containing those "constant" values.  Wherever your memory ends up being is indeed runtime (and therefore OS version) specific.  I've been trapped by similar things in the past by switching compilers or optimizer options.

As you mention keeping raw pointers to std::string instances in raw arrays, such errors are indeed not all to improbable, but may be difficult to detect, as using a DEBUG build won't give you any iterator checks with all these all to RAW things...  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing its the order of evaluation that is causing the issue. Its because of the constant char arrays at the beginning and end

```
const char VAL_TAG_OPEN[]   = "<value>";
const char VAL_TAG_CLOSE[]  = "</value>"
```

The concatenation operator thought VAL_TAG_OPN and VAL_TAG_CLOSE as not a null terminator string. Hence the optimizer just ignored them thinking it as garbage.

```
sAttr += std::string(VAL_TAG_OPEN);
sAttr += *sVal;
sAttr += std::string(VAL_TAG_CLOSE);
```

This does solve it.

Comment: Well, first: Good that this nonsense on order of evaluation is now refuted. Second: Still, this _should_ not make any difference.  What compiler are you using? I'm still puzzled by this, as it makes me nervous that I've a blind spot on some important part of C++...

Comment: The original code works well in VS all versions. The customer ported the code to linux with gcc (don't know the version though). This works without a flaw on most linux machines they have except one. I really wanted to get more info, but customer has no patience and they are happy with the fix. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
sAttr = sAttr+VAL_TAG_OPEN+sVal->c_str()+VAL_TAG_CLOSE;
```

Like fbonnet said, it's an order of evaluation issue.

If that line gets evaluated strictly left to right, then the result of each addition is a std::string object, which has an operator overload for addition and things work as you expect.

If it doesn't get evaluated left to right, then you wind up adding pointers together and who knows what that will get you.

Avoid this construct and just use the += operator on std::string.

Comment: No, it can't be an order of evaluation thing.  left-/right-binding of an operator is independent of the order of evaluation, the type of an expression depends on the expression and not on the run-time execution order!